# Extract text from numerous PDF and Word files

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word

A lawyer friend of mine has thousands of files in PDF and Word format. He would like to extract the name and email addresses from these files, preferably in a CSV or Excel format. The files are not in a consistent structure/layout either.

Can someone suggest paid or free software to handle this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [python](http://www.python.org/) solution.

If the word files are in .docx format then [python](http://www.python.org/) has a number of libraries such as [docxpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docxpy) and [docx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx) that allow extracting the text from word docx files. *(In one utility that I use for processing word files I use python to use word to convert any .doc files to a temporary .docx format file).*

In computer generated PDF files the text is also available and can be extracted using the python [pdfminer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer) library - *otherwise you are looking at using OCR which is error prone.*

Once you have the text content of the file the python [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) or [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) libraries makes short work of locating email addresses and, given that the name elements probably follow a predictable placement and pattern they can almost certainly also be located.

Output to .csv format is simple with the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library *and there are also libraries for writing to excel format directly*.

All of the above are Free, Gratis & Open Source and will run under multiple operating systems - it just needs someone to do a few hours work - while there is a lot of help online there are also books that can help such as [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/). *I am not the author or in any other way associated with this book!*

Comment: Python is some kind of programming language and not really a software. I am not shure that a lawyer has programming skills.

Comment: My experience is that *most* lawyers are smart people and python is widely mentioned as a language that is quick to pick up - I am reasonably sure that they could, possibly with a little help, make use of the software mentioned above successfully.

Comment: I have not said that lawyers are stupied or something like that, but programming is something complete diferent, that what lawyers do. And Python is a realy strange programming language, not easy to learn even for people with programming knowledge.